# add 1 month from current date using java.sql.Date

Tags: java, mysql, date

Hello i have a problem with the result of java.sql.Date. This is my code with adding 1 week from current date

```
Date kini = new Date();
java.sql.Date jadwalPengobatan = new java.sql.Date(kini.getTime()+7*24*60*60*1000);
```

If current date is 2016-02-27, then the result in my MySQL is 2016-03-05.
But if i want to add 1 month (for my case its always 31 days) from current date using this line code

```
 java.sql.Date jadwalPengobatan = new java.sql.Date(kini.getTime()+31*24*60*60*1000);
```

It should be 2016-03-28 but in my MySQL result is 2016-02-05. Anyone can help me whats wrong with this result??

Comment: `mysql` tag here is inappropriate.

Comment: You should do this by Java 8, like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23264495/3728901
`timeStamp.toLocalDateTime().addMonth(1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that you are not doing the calculations in `long`.

You have to replace `31*24*60*60*1000` with `31l*24l*60l*60l*1000l`.

Here is the corrected code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Date kini = new Date();
    java.sql.Date jadwalPengobatan = new java.sql.Date(kini.getTime() + 31l*24l*60l*60l*1000l);
    System.out.println(jadwalPengobatan);
}
```

Please note that this will only fix your calculation where you are adding `31` days to the current date. If you are looking to add a month which can be of `30`, `28` or `29` days also then perhaps you should make use of `Calendar`.

Today's Date:

```
2016-02-27
```

Output:

```
2016-03-29
```

Comment: What about the month of February?  What about leap years?

Comment: I know, but here he just wants to add `31` days and the problem which he has mentioned is calculation related. Have I missed anything?

Comment: He never mentioned 31 days.  I see using `Calendar` in Java or using `DATE_ADD()` as being the only options.

Comment: with my code it is any problem if the year is changed??and yeah your solution is work for me for now..thanks

Comment: @Dylan No it won't be a problem. The only thing is that it will always add `31` days to any given date.

Comment: @Dylan It will work perfectly then. No matter if year changes. :)

Comment: anyway can you give me a link why i should add letter l after the number??@user2004685

Comment: @Dylan `l` is used to force the calculation in `long`. If you do not specify `l` and have all integers such as `31 * 60 * 24 * ... ` then it will do the calculation in int and will overflow.

Answer (score 3):

## java.time

The other Answers use the outmoded old date-time classes. After proving to be confusing, troublesome, and flawed, they have been supplanted by the java.time framework in Java 8 and later.

Do not use the *java.sql* classes in your business logic. They are a messy extension of those old date-time classes, and are a badly-designed hack. Use them only for transferring your data in/out of the database. Convert to java.time types immediately.

To convert, use the new methods added to the old classes.

In the case of [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), it is pretending to hold a date-only value without time-of-day nor time zone. The java.time classes include a true date-only value, `LocalDate`. To convert from `java.sql.Date` to `java.time.LocalDate`, call [`java.sql.Date::toLocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toLocalDate--).

```
LocalDate ld = mySqlDate.toLocalDate();
```

Adding a true month is built-in.

```
LocalDate monthLater = ld.plusMonths( 1 );
```

Convert back to java.sql for storage in the database.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( monthLater );
```

Hopefully some day we will see the JDBC drivers updated to support the java.time types directly. Then the java.sql types will fade away as old relics of the past. But until then we need to perform these *java.sql* ↔ *java.time* conversions.

Update: JDBC 4.2 and later provides for passing java.time types directly with `PreparedStatement::setObject`, and fetching with `ResultSet::getObject`. So no need for conversion to java.sql types.

Answer (score 1):

Use Calendar:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
Date result = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: thanks @Sardor..it will become a reference in the future

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem would be to alter the date in MySQL using the `DATE_ADD()` function:

```
DATE_ADD(yourDate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SimpleDateFormat date= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new Date()); 
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1); 
    String output= date.format(calendar.getTime());

java.sql.Date jadwalPengobatan = new java.sql.Date(output);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer..it will become a reference for me in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following, using `Calendar`:

```
Date kini = new Date(); 
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(kini);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7); // add 10 days, e.g. 1 week
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 31); // add 31 days, e.g. ~1 month
java.sql.Date jadwalPengobatan = new java.sql.Date(cal.getTime());
```

Also see [this discussion](http://www.coderanch.com/t/428375/java/java/add-days-currentDate-java-util).

Comment: thanks @Froodooo it will become a reference in the future