# how to decrement dd/MM/yyyyy days -1

Tags: java, oracle-adf

```
AttributeBinding attrs = 
    (AttributeBinding)bindingss.getControlBinding("FagDatfin");`

SimpleDateFormat fts = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dateattrs = fts.format(attrs);
System.out.println(dateattrs);
Date date = fts.parse(dateattrs);`

attrs.setInputValue(date);
```

how to decrement days -1 for example `23/04/2018` change to `22/04/2019`

Comment: prefer to use LocalDate rather than Date. Date is obsolete. LocalDate comes with its own, better-designed use classes and formatters. Then use plusDays(-1).

Answer (score 2):

From Java 8, you can use `DateTimeFormatter` instead of `SimpleDateFormat`.

You will be able to convert the String to a `LocalDate`, which contains handy methods like... `minusDays()` :

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.from(dateTimeFormatter.parse("23/04/2018")).minusDays(1);
System.out.println(dateTimeFormatter.format(localDate));
```

Comment: if change LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.from(dateTimeFormatter.parse("23/04/2018")).minusDays(1); change                  LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.from(dateTimeFormatter.parse("attrs")).minusDays(1);
 Erreur

Comment: @Souhaiel `dateTimeFormatter.parse("attrs")` does not make sense. You should parse a date. Somehing like `dateTimeFormatter.parse("25/12/2019")`

Comment: i like change this attribute value FagDatfin in AttributeBinding attrs = (AttributeBinding)bindingss.getControlBinding("FagDatfin");`AttributeBinding attrs = (AttributeBinding)bindingss.getControlBinding("FagDatfin");
              
                 DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
                 LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.from(dateTimeFormatter.parse("attrs")).minusDays(1);
                 System.out.println("test"+dateTimeFormatter.format(localDate));

Comment: @Souhaiel Can you try `dateTimeFormatter.parse(attrs.getInputValue())` ?

Comment: problem in type attribute FagDatfin  TimesTamp but my value String

Comment: @Souhaiel then [convert your Timestamp to a LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263490/how-to-convert-java-sql-timestamp-to-localdate-java8-java-time)