# Convert GMT Timestamp to local Calendar to particular timezone

Tags: java, calendar

I am trying to convert GMT timestamp to local timestamp with particular timezone

This is what I have implemented

```
public static void test(Timestamp p_gmtTime, String p_timeZone) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat tzFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:MM:SS a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        tzFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(p_timeZone)); // Use whatever timezone
        tzFormat.format(p_gmtTime);
        //System.out.println(tzFormat.format(p_gmtTime)); // This line gives correct o/p
        
        Calendar calendar = tzFormat.getCalendar();
        
        //calendar.setTime(tzFormat.parse(format));
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime()); // this line gives wrong result
    }
```

Issue comes when there is daylight savings are on, then it gives future date instead of current date,
lets say If I do transaction today `30-Dec-2021` it gives date of `31-Dec-2021`
and I have limitation to use only `calendar` object.
I need help in converting GMT Timestamp to local Timestamp with particular timezone

Comment: Didn't we already do this?  Stop using `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat` and, in general, the `java.util.Date` classes.  Instead, make use of the `java.time` APIs instead, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263490/how-to-convert-java-sql-timestamp-to-localdate-java8-java-time)

Comment: yes but I have limitation to use only those classes.

Comment: Any reason why are restricted to using (out-of-date and bug riddled) APIs?  Could use one of the back port APIs?

Comment: Its a very old application and function is used from many other places, dont want to disturb other classes.

Comment: If you're using Java 8+ you get `java.time` for free, otherwise, you're going to have to live with these (continuing) issues :P

Comment: I hope that this can give you a start if I understand the question, if not apologies.

`LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = zone.getRules().getOffset(ldt);
  ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atOffset(zoneOffset)
 .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(timezone));
  DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmm");
  String date = dtf.format(zdt);`

Comment: `p_gmtTime.toInstant().atZone( ZoneId.of( p_timeZone ) ).toString()`